# Find sup and inf of $\frac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3}$. Did I do it right?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need to find sup and inf of: $\frac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3}$. Now I know that I can proof form the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 >= abc+bcd+cda+dab$ so I know that the sup = 1 and the expression = 1 for a=b=c=d=1. On the other hand I see that for a = 1, b = 1, c = 1 and d = n, if $n \implies \infty$ then $\frac{1+n+n+n}{1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + n^3} =\frac{3n+1}{n^3 + 3} \implies 0 $ and $0$ is never reached. But is that enough to call my thinking a formal proof of sup and inf?

Comment: As to whether you have a formal proof depends on 1) How you write it up, and 2) Your intended audience. E.g. I would prefer a line explaining that the expression $ > 0$ (which arguably is obvious, but is necessary to demonstrate that you indeed have the inf.

Comment: Yeah I think about showing that with Archimedes' Axiom and a very small ε. We will see if that works. Thank you for you contribution Sir!